# Matrix determinant $b_{ij}=c^{i-j}a_{ij}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I found this problem in A. Kostrikin's algebra book. There is no solution or a hint to it there. Only answer: $\det B=a$.

Let $A = [a_{ij}] \in \mathcal{M}(n,n; K), \ \det A=a, \ \ c \in K, c \neq0$

$B= [b_{ij}] \in \mathcal{M}(n,n; K), \ \ b_{ij}=c^{i-j}a_{ij}, \ \ \ i,j \in \{ 1,2,\dots,n\}$.

I drew (wrote down) both matrices but I don't see how $\det B$ can be equal to $\det A$.

Could you help me?

Comment: What is your definition of $\det$? Are you using permutations?

Comment: It depends. But mostly Laplace's theorem or Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because $B=\begin{pmatrix}c^1\\&c^2\\&&\ddots\\&&&c^n\end{pmatrix}A\begin{pmatrix}c^1\\&c^2\\&&\ddots\\&&&c^n\end{pmatrix}^{-1}.$

Comment: What is $c_1,\ldots, c_n$?

Comment: @Sigur Typo. Should be $c^1,\ldots,c^n$, i.e. the powers of $c$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me, though, how you came up with this :) ?

Comment: @Hagrid I simply have seen this kind of matrix similarity many times.